# getting the result of a sql statement in vs2010 vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am doing a sql statement to get all the data that starts with "A" in the database.

```
Sub searchMap()
    Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("WeddingPerfectionConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    connection.Open()
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT LocationName FROM MapSearch WHERE LocationName=" Like ("1%")
    Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
    Dim customerId As Integer
    If (reader.Read()) Then
        customerId = reader.GetValue(0)
    End If
    reader.Close()
End Sub
```

And i would like to get the result and display it in a lable.

How can i go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL-Server:

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT LocationID, LocationName FROM MapSearch WHERE LocationName LIKE 'A%'"
```

[LIKE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

Comment: For example my database have "Boy" and "Apple".
Such that with the user type "A" into the text box.
My sql statement will search for any word start with "A".
And my Label1 will display the result - "Apple"

Comment: @beny: so you only want to show one word even if there are multiple in database? Edited my answer to show how you only select one record even if there are more than one.

Comment: @beny: How do you want to show all words, what separator do you want?

Comment: Hmm.. I not very sure about the separator is it possible to show it in a listbox? or anything that allow user to click on any one of the result displayed?

Comment: @Beny: In your question you asked how to display the reult in a label and not in a Listbox. But anyway, you have the answer: `LIKE 'A%'` will return all records where `LocationName` starts with an `A`. But you should also select the `ID` column to set the `DataValueField`. http://shalvinpd.blogspot.com/2008/03/sqldatareader-and-aspnet-listbox.html